# How to store an object with separate properties in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Still pretty new to Redux, and I've gotten decent at saving single values to the store, but I am a bit confused on how to store multiple related properties on an object.

This seems to be related to the use of `Object.assign(...` but I'm not sure quite how to do it.

Would the correct method to save additional properties be something like this:

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){

      case actionTypes.SAVE_ENGAGEMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        engagement: Object.assign({}, action.engagement)
      };
      default:
            return state;
    }
  };
```

Basically I want an object with properties like such in my store:

```
{
'engagement': 5,
'opened_from_push': true,
'first_accessed_time': 1561927084
}
```

Ideally I would be able to update it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Redux requires you to not mutate the state but return a new one.
So I think you just need to do like this.

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
      case actionTypes.SAVE_ENGAGEMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        engagement: action.payload,
      };
      case actionTypes.SAVE_OPENED_FROM_PUSH:
      return {
        ...state,
        opened_from_push: action.payload,
      };
      case actionTypes.FIRST_ACCESSED_TIME:
      return {
        ...state,
        first_accessed_time: action.payload,
      };
      default:
      return state;
    }
  };
```

Comment: And this won't overwrite my object properties, correct?

Comment: Please let me know what you mean by object here. The state is also an object and with this, it wont be mutated.

Comment: I mean that when I save a value to my store, it won't overwrite other properties in the store associated with this reducer (other than the value I am saving), correct? Sorry, I'm still trying to figure out everything of how Redux works. I have found it... complicated.

Comment: Yes. Everything else in the object is represented by ...state.

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the case, but I just wanted to check. I'm going to check that this does what I want it to do and then I'll accept your answer. Sorry for such a newbie question, but I've found Redux very difficult to wrap my head around effectively.

Comment: You should definitely go through the redux tutorial in egghead.io by Dan Abramov.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator for your incoming object as well:

```
const state = {
  engagement: 5,
  greeting: true
};


const engagement = {
  engagement: 6,
  opened_from_push: true,
  first_accessed_time: 1561927084
}

return { ...state, ...engagment };
```

Note that the engagement comes second which will override keys, so your `state.engagement` will end up as 6 in this example.